# How to perform Forecasting in Qliksense cloud?

Tags: cloud, forecasting, qliksense

I am having three columns,

1. customerId
2. yearMonth (ex: 2013-01, 2013-02 upto 2016-08)
3. sales

How can I calculate forecasting for the yearMonth 2016-09 in Qliksense cloud?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you want to calculate your forecast, here's an example I have found

```
if(SUM(Revenue),SUM(Revenue),
linest_m(total aggr(if(SUM(Revenue),SUM(Revenue)),Date),Date)* 
only({1}Date)
+linest_b(total aggr(if(SUM(Revenue),SUM(Revenue)),Date),Date))
```

which uses the very simple y=mx+b to calculate the straight line. If you project your [Date] forward, the line will be projected forward as well.

This created a set "MMM-YYYY" of 12 months behind, 3 months ahead:

```
Let varMinDate = Num(MonthStart(AddMonths(Today(),-12)));


TempCalendar:
LOAD
               Date(AddMonths($(varMinDate), + RecNo() - 1),'MMM-YYYY') as Date
AutoGenerate 15;
```

[answer sauce](https://community.qlikview.com/thread/188208)